# Getting device attach or removal notifications

Tags: c++, c, winapi

How do I get device(In my case a "logical volume") attach or removal notifications before "Safe to remove" or "Device cannot be detached" messages are shown?

I want to catch device notifications before they are processed by any application. Is there any way to get device notifications before all the applications?

Comment: Please clarify: On what systems do you intend to run your program?

Comment: Windows operating system. I want to do it using Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

Your application can listen for [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480.aspx) messages. The `wParam` parameter specifies the type of event and the `lParam` parameter contains event specific information.

> Is there any way to get device notifications before all the applications?

No, that's not going to be possible. Imagine if it was possible and two applications were running that desired to both win the race. Clearly they cannot both win.

Comment: He said he wanted to be the first one to catch the notification, which a) might not be guaranteed by that message (but I don't know) and b) I don't think is even possible. @SamL why do you want to be the first?

Comment: As I read, WM_DEVICECHANGE is broadcast by system, so is there any defined sequence or hierarchy that messages will be caught by applications? I want to see if Windows OS is the first to get this message or any other application. One more confusion: As device arrival produces hardware interrupt, so who is the first to get notification, Windows OS or a device driver(Though device drivers are part of OS)? So if I catch notification at driver level, so will I be the first?

Comment: You want to write a device driver that replaces the system recognition of devices?! Why would you expect that to end well? It doesn't sound to me as though you are going about solving your problem in a realistic way. What you are describing would be a modded OS. Of course, I've no idea what your actual problem is. Never mind.

Comment: So, it seems to be, device driver is the only answer to my problem(though i am not going to write it).

Comment: Well, you haven't yet told us what your problem is. You've told us how you plan to solve your problem. There's a subtle difference.

Comment: Sometimes when we try to eject USB, "Device in use" prompt appears. I was just wondering if this prompt can be skipped. Because though I closed all the files & folders from that device, still prompt appeared. That's it.

Comment: The system is giving you that dialog because the device still is in use. Writes are cached and the system is flushing those writes. But that's a completely different question. I think I answered the question that you asked.

Comment: Yes, you have given answer to my question. Thanks for your help!